# Ambiguous function declaration

Tags: c++

I have such code:

```
int fun(int());
```

What does it exactly do? As far as I know it is equivalent to declaration of function taking pointer to function

```
int fun(int (*ptr)())
```

but I'm not sure why.

Comment: Are you asking why it's not a variable? (*"most vexing parse"*) Or why `int()` turned into `int(*)()`? (that's what always happens with functions used as parameters)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I wasn't sure about second part (   int() to int(*)()  )

Answer (score 5):

These are all the same:

```
int f( int()     );
int f( int(*)()  );
int f( int(*p)() );
int f( int p()   );
int f( int(p)()  );
```

- There is a language rule that if you declare a function parameter as having function type, it is adjusted to having function pointer type.
- The name of a parameter can be omitted.